# PM2 + apache2 Optimization

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, node.js

I am running a Node.js application with PM2 as a reverse proxy through Apache on my Centos 7 server. The website experiences very slow loading times, and its performance is quite poor. Can anyone suggest methods to improve its performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Review your application code for any performance bottlenecks, such as inefficient algorithms or database queries.
2. Implement caching for frequently accessed data to reduce the load on your server.
3. If your Node.js application interacts with a database, make sure your queries are optimized
4. Review your PM2 configuration to ensure that your Node.js application is running with optimal settings. Adjust the number of instances, memory allocation, and CPU affinity as needed.
5. Check your Apache reverse proxy settings to make sure they are correctly forwarding requests to your Node.js application. Ensure that proxy modules like `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` are enabled and configured properly.
6. Ensure that your server has sufficient `CPU, memory, and network resources to handle the expected traffic. Monitor server performance using tools like` top, htop` to identify resource bottlenecks.
7. Use monitoring tools like PM2's built-in monitoring features or application-specific tools to track and diagnose performance issues in real time.

Comment: My server is unable to fully utilize all of its resources. It has 64GB of RAM, but as I monitor it, I can see that it only consumes up to 16GB of RAM. Additionally, the processors are not being fully utilized.

Comment: The application was purchased from the official Envato Market Official website, so there should be no concerns about its code

Comment: If it's a purchased application you should be eligible for support. Use it.

Comment: You should check the website in the inspect element network tab and see the waterfall of loading pages. you will get the exact URL of the file which is causing the issue. Secondly, I would suggest you use CDN to serve static content faster.